# Rails 3: orphan "Edit" and "Delete" links in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a primitive to-do list app with tasks belonging to projects. In the View I'm showing tasks beneath the related project with the links to edit and delete each one.

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>

<h2><%= project.name %></h2>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %>
<%= link_to 'Destroy', project_path(project), 
   method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<%= form_for([project, project.tasks.new]) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<% project.tasks.each do |task| %>
<%= task.name %>
<%= link_to 'Destroy Task', [task.project, task],
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<%= link_to 'Edit Task', edit_project_task_path(task.project, task) %>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New TODO list', new_project_path %>
```

However, in the rendered page, there are 2 more Edit and Destroy links than expected.
The links lead to ../projects/id/tasks/ and ../projects/id/tasks//edit

This is the task Model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

and here is the task Controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.create(params[:task].permit(:name, :completed))
    redirect_to projects_path
  end
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    redirect_to projects_path
  end
  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id]) 
    redirect_to projects_path
  end
end
```

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "../projects/id/tasks/ and ../projects/id/tasks//edit"?

Comment: What do you mean there are 2 more than expected? Does each task have 2 edit links and 2 delete links?

Comment: @Jun Zhou  these are paths for the orphan links

Comment: @Samo yes, these are 2 more than expected, no these 2 orphan links appear once for each project

Comment: Please paste your tasks controller and model code here.

Comment: @RailsGuy just updated the question.

Comment: Paste the code, where you are creating a post and showing post's list.

Comment: @RailsGuy, it's actually not the loop, which causes orphan links, they are due to the form for new task

Comment: Yes, I know that, There are creating two records for each tasks, one with without information. just add one validation (validates :name, presence: true) in your task model and see what happen. let me know as well.

Comment: add your code in github or somewhere else, I will make necessary changes in it.

Comment: @RailsGuy here's the repo https://bitbucket.org/v_to_l/tasker/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected behaviour, because you put your links in 2 loops, one for `@projects` and other one for `@tasks`. That's why it is happening.
you should do this:

```
<% @tasks = @projects.map{|x| x.tasks} %>    
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <%= task.project.name %>
  <ul>    
    <li><%= task.name %>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy Task', project_task_path(task.project, task),
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit Task', edit_project_task_path(task.project, task) %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

I am re-factoring your tasks code as well,

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  before_action :load_task, except: :create

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.create(params[:task].permit(:name, :completed))
    redirect_to projects_path
  end

  def destroy       
    @task.destroy
    redirect_to projects_path
  end

  def edit       
  end

  def update        
    redirect_to projects_path
  end

 private
  def load_task
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id]) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but this doesn't seem to work for me. It returns "undefined method `name' for #<Arel::SelectManager:0x18e06d0>" , though the tasks table does have this column